# Sketch: Pixel grid behaviour

Tags: sketch-app, pixel-grid

Ok, so I want to create an outline-icon. Therefore I made a rectangle and chose to have my border centred, so that round corners are actually round on both sides. In order for it to be pixel-perfect, I want the border to lie on the pixels and not between them, like this:

[image: Rectangle aligned the way I want it to]

However Sketch keeps rearranging my rectangle the way I do not want it:

[image: Sketch not letting me align my rectangle]

Now, when I edit vector-points I can choose how sketch places these in relation to the pixel-grid:

[image: Option for vector points]

Is there some similar option for aligning objects, rather than their anchor-points? Because this is driving me crazy. Even if I duplicate a perfectly aligned rectangle using alt/option + drag, it moves both of them to lie between pixels ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use illustrator and Inkscape, might I suggested you change the border to outside or outer. Based on the gif you posted you have it on centre, basically Sketch is snapping your rectangle to its anchor points, if the stroke is set to inside or outer alignment that could solve your problem.

Outlining the object's stroke will help with aligning to the grid. Make sure to retain the original incase you need to make edits.

Comment: Indeed. However the problem with this solution is that then either the inner or outer edges of my border will not be round whenever there is a corner. That is why I put it on centre in the first place :/

Comment: Outline the strokes. Should serve as quick solution. Make sure you keep a copy of the original.

Comment: good point. Can you post that as another answer? I'll mark it as the correct one then as this solved my problem :)

Comment: Or rather edit your current one to also include this option. That's probably a better idea

Comment: Most definitely. Out of curiosity does sketch allow you to run scripts and actions the way illustrator and Inkscape do?

Comment: to be fair, I myself am relatively new to sketch, so I might have missed something, however I don't think it allows you to do that. What is quite cool about Sketch, however, is that it has quite the active dev-community that are making a ton of useful plugins. When it comes to features for designing logos, etc, Illustrator is still far superior. Sketch's main advantage is that it can handle a lot (a LOT!) more artboards without slowing down which is especially useful for designing UI / UX, where it is a benefit to have every screen in one file so you can keep your consistency.

Comment: I'm used to working illustrator but have been considering giving sketch a shot purely just for making icons and some ui elements. I'll take a look at their online documentation to poke around. If they have an active dev community that means they're looking to add or expand functionality.